# Search Bar in React: Suggestions and Query Mismatch because of setState

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am basically creating a search bar for city suggestions. Which calls an API and based on that I show the suggestions. But since I have to call setState there is a mismatch in query and suggestions.

Recreating the error: If you type Indore and clear the query completely by backspace in one continuous stroke. You can still see a suggestion left even though the input field is empty.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputText: "",
      listItems: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event){
    if (event.target.value.length > 0){
      var apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_HERE_API_KEY;
      fetch("https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?apikey="+ apiKey +"&query="+event.target.value)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        data = data.suggestions;
        var lst = []
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
          if (data[i].matchLevel === "city") {
            var city = data[i].address.city;
            var state = data[i].address.state;
            var country = data[i].address.country;
            var finalString = city;
            if (state !== undefined) {
              finalString += ", "+state;
            }
            if (country !== undefined) {
              finalString += ", "+country;
            }
            if (i === data.length - 1) {
              lst.push(<li className="search-result-last-item" key={city}>{finalString}</li>)
            }
            else {
              lst.push(<li key={city}>{finalString}</li>)
            }
          }
        }
        this.setState({
          listItems: lst
        });
      })
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        listItems: []
      })
    }
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="search-box">
          <input className="search-input" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
          <ul className="search-result">
            {this.state.listItems}
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing condition on **target.length**, instead let the API fetch the data and decides whether there's is data or not and call setState accordingly.

Comment: I guess the mismatch is occurring because of multiple setState calls and when you clear all the text, multiple setState calls fire up and your last call to empty the list runs earlier than the setState calls occurring in your promise API call.

Comment: Yeah that is the case. What can be the solution?

Comment: Did you apply the fix I told you earlier? That might do your job. As by that, setState will always called when you’ll receive response from the API and in case of empty text, data will be empty and so your list.

Comment: Actually thats not the problem. Problem is if I give an input I will have results of previous input persisting. It is because of the latency between giving input and fetching results.

Comment: You mean every input fetches data and display the result of previous input not latest or it always persist first data fetched?